# Strange error in Apple Core Data tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I was doing the [Apple Core Data Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/02_RootViewController.html), and on the first occasion I was suggested to build the project, I got this error:

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Locations-fajvunxiruohofbhzimrgekrpnqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Locations.app/Locations normal i386
    cd "/Users/user/Documents/xcode projects/Locations"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Locations-fajvunxiruohofbhzimrgekrpnqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Locations-fajvunxiruohofbhzimrgekrpnqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Locations-fajvunxiruohofbhzimrgekrpnqh/Build/Intermediates/Locations.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Locations.build/Objects-normal/i386/Locations.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Locations-fajvunxiruohofbhzimrgekrpnqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Locations.app/Locations

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
  "_kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters", referenced from:
      -[RootViewController locationManager] in RootViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use XCode 4.0.2, Mac OS X 10.6.8. What can be the cause of this? I followed the tutorial step-by-step and have absolutely no idea what could go wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import the CoreLocation framework. This can be done by going to the **Project - Build Phases - Link Binary with Libraries**

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to add the CoreLocation framework to the linked frameworks of the project.

In the project settings, select the application target and under "Build Phases" add it to the "Link Binary With Libraries" step.

Answer (score 1):

When you started the project did you select "Use Core Data For Storage"? I think it adds a framework you need.

click on your project in the navigation pane (apple + 1)

targets -> your project-> build phases -> link binaries with libraries -> +

then select **CoreData.framework** and add.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the .m file is dropped out of the 'Compiled sources' list in XCode. You need to add the .m file manually:

Build phases > Compiled sources > (check for if your .m file is indeed missing) > Add .m file > Build